# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$router') vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So I'm trying to redirect user to diffrent route if api call returns status 422. but I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$router')
```

my routes.js:

```
{
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        name: 'Dashboard',
        beforeEnter: (to, form, next) =>{
            axios.get('/api/authenticated')
                .then(()=>{
                    next();
                }).catch(()=>{
                    return next({ name: 'Login'})
            })
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'documentCollections',
                component: DocumentCollection,
                name: 'DocumentCollections'
            },
            {
                path: 'document',
                component: Document,
                name: 'Document'
            },
            {
                path: 'createDocument',
                component: CreateDocument,
                name: 'CreateDocument'
            },
            {
                path: 'suppliers',
                component: Suppliers,
                name: 'Suppliers'
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                component: Settings,
                name: 'Settings'
            },
        ]
}
```

I also have login/register components and when I use

```
this.$router.push({ name: "DocumentCollections"});
```

It redirects user without any error. The problem is when I am in children component of dashboard component.

in documentCollections component i have a method:

```
    loadCollections(){
        axios.get('/api/documentCollections')
            .then((response) => {
                this.Collections = response.data.data
                this.disableButtons(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                if(error.response.status === 422){
                    //here is where the error happens
                    this.$router.push({ name: "Settings"});
                }
            });
    },
```

That loads collections but if user has some data set null api return status 422. and I want him to be redirected to Settings component.
(both documentCollection and Settings are child components of Dashboard)

why doesn't this.$router.push work here but works in login/register component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `this` inside a callback function creates a new binding to the `this` object instead of the Vue object in a regular function expression.

You can use the arrow syntax to define the function, so `this` won't be overwritten.

```
.catch((error) => {
    if(error.response.status === 422){
        this.$router.push({name: "Settings"});
    }
})
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

### Another option

Define another instance of `this` before the axios call and use it after you received the response.

```
let self = this
...
self.$router.push({name: "Settings"})
```

**With your code**

```
loadCollections(){
    let self = this;
    axios.get('/api/documentCollections')
        .then((response) => {
            this.Collections = response.data.data
            this.disableButtons(response.data.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            if(error.response.status === 422){
                self.$router.push({name: "Settings"});
            }
        });
},
```

Answer (score 8):

If using Composition API:

```js
// Import
import router from "@/router";

//and use
router.push({name: "Settings"});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).